# Getting correct English grammar

Tags: c++

Does someone know of a better way to get proper grammar in sentences than this method of mine? I don't want to continue with this for my entire huge program if there is a much more elegant way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum Gender {Male, Female};
enum Capitalized {Capital, NonCapital};

struct Person {
    std::string name;
    Gender gender;
    Person (const std::string& newName, Gender sex) : name (newName), gender (sex) {}
} *you;


std::string youHeShe (const Person* person, Capitalized capital = NonCapital) {
    return (capital == NonCapital) ? 
        ( (person == you) ? "you" : (person->gender == Male) ? "he" : "she" ) :
        ( (person == you) ? "You" : (person->gender == Male) ? "He" : "She" );
}

std::string isAre (const Person* person) {
    return (person == you) ? "are" : "is";
}

std::string verb (const Person* person, const std::string& verb) {
    return (person == you) ? verb : verb + "s";
}

int main() {
    std::string yourName;
    std::cout << "What is your name? ";
    std::getline (std::cin, yourName);
    you = new Person (yourName, Male); 
    Person *mary = new Person ("Mary", Female), *bob = new Person ("Bob", Male);
    Person* people[] = {you, mary, bob};
    for (const Person* x : people)
        std::cout << youHeShe(x, Capital) << " (" << x->name << ") " << isAre(x) << 
        " awesome because " << youHeShe(x) << " " << verb(x, "rock") << "!" << std::endl;
}
```

**Output:**

> What is your name? John Doe
>
> You (John Doe) are awesome because you rock!
>
> She (Mary) is awesome because she rocks!
>
> He (Bob) is awesome because he rocks!

In my program, there are sentences involving either the 3rd person or the 2nd person, so the grammar has to be correct based on which it is.

Of course, my method will involve many more such grammar functions, but I just need to know if there is a better way before I write those other functions (and special cases).

Comment: All of those pointers should be `Person`s.

Comment: Way too many pointers and you have objects that you dynamically allocate with `new` and don't `delete`.

Comment: But all my Person objects in my program are already pointers.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this without some clarification on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you would need to write 3 different sentences for every out you want.
Format strings can help here (maybe not in the edge cases - however you have given no example of those)

"%s rock%s!".
The first string is then either "You", "He", or "She".
The second one is for the "He, She, It the s must fit" rule.

What about the am/are/is/... distinction? You could configure a place holder

```
#define ARE_IS "{AREIS}"
const std::string DUMB_MESSAGE = "%s" ARE_IS " dumb!";
```

and then replace ARE_IS with the correct form.

How fitting this solution is, how flexible and how much work you will have with that - we can't guess that with the information given.

Answer (score 1):

**Pronouns into the Person structure**

You should put the gender pronouns into the `Person` structure:

```
struct Person
{
    std::string name;
    Gender      gender;
    std::string pronoun;
    Person (const std::string& newName, Gender sex)
       : name (newName), gender (sex)
    {
       switch(gender)
       {
         case Male: pronoun = "he"; break;
         case Female: pronoun = "she"; break;
         default: pronoun = "it"; break;
       }
    }

    }
};
```

**Comparing pointers vs. content**
In the function `isAre` you are comparing pointers, not content:

```
std::string isAre (const Person* person)
{
    return (person == you) ? "are" : "is";
}
```

The function will only work correctly if the **pointer** to `person` and the **pointer** to `you` are **pointing to the same object**.
You want to dereference the pointers before comparing:

```
std::string isAre (const Person* person)
{
    return (*person == *you) ? "are" : "is";
}
```

**Pointers are difficult, use references**
In C++, you should be passing instances of structures by reference not pointer:

```
struct Person you;
std::string isAre (const Person& person)
{
    return (person == you) ? "are" : "is";
}
```

This will help avoid run-time issues like not allocating memory for a `Person` and having the `you` pointer point to the allocated memory.

**C++ is not Java or C#, don't use `new`**
In C++, prefer not to dynamically allocate memory unless absolutely necessary.  You can simply declare a variable and use it:

```
std::getline (std::cin, yourName);
Person you(yourName, Male);
Person mary("Mary", Female);
Person bob("Bob", Male);
std::vector<Person> people;
people.push_back(you);
people.push_back(mary);
people.push_back(bob);
```